# Beta regression: slope of scaled predictor

Tags: r, logistic, regression-coefficients, odds, beta-regression

I want to fit a **beta regression with an scaled continuous predictor, and express the slope in terms of proportion (not at the transformed, log-odds scale)**. In other words, I would like to express the change in the response variable (a proportion), when the predictor increases 1 standard deviation from the mean.

**I can get the slope at the probability scale with the `emmeans::emtrends()` function, but I don't know how to do it manually from the model output.** In contrast, I can back-transform and interpret intercepts and factor coefficients manually, or so I think. The fact that I cannot do the same for an scaled continuous predictor suggests I don't understand my model very well. Can anyone shed light on this?

I have found some inspiration in previous questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297659/interpretation-of-betareg-coef), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137786/relationship-between-beta-1-and-odds-in-simple-logistic-regression) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442789/interpretation-of-the-beta-regression-coefficients-with-logit-link-used-to-analy).

See below a reproducible example, showing manual calculation of intercepts, factor coefficients, and slopes.

Note that `emmeans::emtrends()` appears to take the scaling into account only when it is done in the input data, not on the model formula.

```r
library(betareg)
library(effects)
#> Loading required package: carData
#> lattice theme set by effectsTheme()
#> See ?effectsTheme for details.
library(emmeans)
library(glmmTMB)
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(visreg)

######### Dataset

data("FoodExpenditure", package = "betareg")
FoodExpenditure$resp <- FoodExpenditure$food / FoodExpenditure$income
FoodExpenditure$income.s <- as.numeric(scale(FoodExpenditure$income))
summary(FoodExpenditure)
#>       food            income         persons           resp       
#>  Min.   : 7.431   Min.   :25.91   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.1075  
#>  1st Qu.:11.069   1st Qu.:42.12   1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:0.2269  
#>  Median :14.831   Median :60.45   Median :3.000   Median :0.2611  
#>  Mean   :15.953   Mean   :58.44   Mean   :3.579   Mean   :0.2897  
#>  3rd Qu.:19.102   3rd Qu.:76.79   3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.:0.3469  
#>  Max.   :28.980   Max.   :88.23   Max.   :7.000   Max.   :0.5612  
#>     income.s      
#>  Min.   :-1.6326  
#>  1st Qu.:-0.8192  
#>  Median : 0.1007  
#>  Mean   : 0.0000  
#>  3rd Qu.: 0.9206  
#>  Max.   : 1.4945


######### The back-transformed intercept from a null model coincides with the sample mean

mean(FoodExpenditure$resp)
#> [1] 0.2896702
summary(glmmTMB(resp ~ 1, data = FoodExpenditure, family = beta_family(link = "logit"), dispformula = ~ 1))
#>  Family: beta  ( logit )
#> Formula:          resp ~ 1
#> Data: FoodExpenditure
#> 
#>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#>    -66.7    -63.4     35.3    -70.7       36 
#> 
#> 
#> Dispersion parameter for beta family (): 20.9 
#> 
#> Conditional model:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  -0.8925     0.0763   -11.7   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
plogis(- 0.8925)
#> [1] 0.2905942


######### Factors: back-transformed coefficients coincide with raw probabilities calculated from the data

mod.factor <- glmmTMB(resp ~ factor(persons), data = FoodExpenditure, family = beta_family(link = "logit"), dispformula = ~ 1)
summary(mod.factor)
#>  Family: beta  ( logit )
#> Formula:          resp ~ factor(persons)
#> Data: FoodExpenditure
#> 
#>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#>    -66.4    -53.3     41.2    -82.4       30 
#> 
#> 
#> Dispersion parameter for beta family (): 28.5 
#> 
#> Conditional model:
#>                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)      -1.06718    0.20873  -5.113 3.17e-07 ***
#> factor(persons)2 -0.09564    0.25723  -0.372  0.71003    
#> factor(persons)3  0.21242    0.25180   0.844  0.39889    
#> factor(persons)4 -0.01733    0.28018  -0.062  0.95068    
#> factor(persons)5  0.26137    0.25112   1.041  0.29796    
#> factor(persons)6  0.77294    0.29930   2.582  0.00981 ** 
#> factor(persons)7  0.45845    0.34230   1.339  0.18046    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

# Raw probabilities from the data
FoodExpenditure %>% group_by(persons) %>% summarise(mean = mean(food/income)) %>% pull(mean)
#> [1] 0.2491281 0.2317299 0.2947887 0.2564000 0.3130861 0.4256767 0.3675447
# Back-transformed probabilities from the model: manually or through estimated marginal means
plogis(c(coef(summary(mod.factor))$cond[1, 1], (coef(summary(mod.factor))$cond[1, 1] + coef(summary(mod.factor))$cond[-1, 1])))
#>                  factor(persons)2 factor(persons)3 factor(persons)4 
#>        0.2559398        0.2381552        0.2984353        0.2526537 
#> factor(persons)5 factor(persons)6 factor(persons)7 
#>        0.3087838        0.4269665        0.3523495
summary(emmeans::emmeans(mod.factor, specs = ~ persons, regrid = "response"))$response
#> [1] 0.2559398 0.2381552 0.2984353 0.2526537 0.3087838 0.4269665 0.3523495



######### Continuous

mean(FoodExpenditure$income)
#> [1] 58.44434
sd(FoodExpenditure$income)
#> [1] 19.93156

# Compare models with and without scaling, and with the scaling done in the model formula or in the data frame
list.model <-
  list(
    "not.scaled" = glmmTMB(resp ~ income, data = FoodExpenditure, family = beta_family(link = "logit"), dispformula = ~ 1),
    "scaled" = glmmTMB(resp ~ scale(income), data = FoodExpenditure, family = beta_family(link = "logit"), dispformula = ~ 1),
    "scaled.df" = glmmTMB(resp ~ income.s, data = FoodExpenditure, family = beta_family(link = "logit"), dispformula = ~ 1)
  )

# Model coefficients
lapply(list.model, function(x) coef(summary(x))$cond[, 1])
#> $not.scaled
#> (Intercept)      income 
#> -0.21032876 -0.01187883 
#> 
#> $scaled
#>   (Intercept) scale(income) 
#>    -0.9045793    -0.2367637 
#> 
#> $scaled.df
#> (Intercept)    income.s 
#>  -0.9045793  -0.2367637

# Coefficients transformed to probabilities by undoing the logit link: scaling yields an intercept that coincides with the sample mean of the response variable (since scaled variables are also centered).
# However, the scaled slope is less straightforward
lapply(list.model, function(x) plogis(coef(summary(x))$cond[, 1]))
#> $not.scaled
#> (Intercept)      income 
#>   0.4476108   0.4970303 
#> 
#> $scaled
#>   (Intercept) scale(income) 
#>     0.2881104     0.4410840 
#> 
#> $scaled.df
#> (Intercept)    income.s 
#>   0.2881104   0.4410840


# Estimated trends at probability scale: scaling only taken into account if declared in the data frame and not in the model's formula
lapply(list.model[1:2], function(x) emmeans::emtrends(x, specs = ~ income, var = "income", regrid = "response"))
#> $not.scaled
#>  income income.trend       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>    58.4     -0.00244 0.000706 35 -0.00387   -0.001
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> 
#> $scaled
#>  income income.trend       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>    58.4     -0.00244 0.000706 35 -0.00387   -0.001
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95
emmeans::emtrends(list.model$scaled.df, specs = ~ income.s, var = "income.s", regrid = "response")
#>   income.s income.s.trend     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  -9.39e-17        -0.0486 0.0141 35  -0.0771    -0.02
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95


### The slope could also be calculated manually at the probability scale from a visualization of the model. However, this is prone to error and hardly practical.

visreg(list.model$scaled, "income", scale = "response")
```

[image]

```r
# Slope, not scaled
(0.375-0.225)/(max(FoodExpenditure$income) - min(FoodExpenditure$income))
#> [1] 0.002406623
# Slope, scaled
(0.375-0.225)/((max(FoodExpenditure$income) - min(FoodExpenditure$income))/sd(FoodExpenditure$income))
#> [1] 0.04796776




sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.utf8   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
#> [5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.utf8    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] visreg_2.7.0          forcats_0.5.1         stringr_1.5.0        
#>  [4] dplyr_1.1.2           purrr_1.0.1           readr_2.1.2          
#>  [7] tidyr_1.3.0           tibble_3.2.1          ggplot2_3.4.0        
#> [10] tidyverse_1.3.1       glmmTMB_1.1.3         emmeans_1.8.5-9000004
#> [13] effects_4.2-1         carData_3.0-5         betareg_3.1-4        
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] nlme_3.1-157        fs_1.5.2            lubridate_1.8.0    
#>  [4] insight_0.19.1.3    httr_1.4.3          numDeriv_2016.8-1.1
#>  [7] tools_4.2.0         TMB_1.8.1           backports_1.4.1    
#> [10] utf8_1.2.2          R6_2.5.1            DBI_1.1.2          
#> [13] colorspace_2.0-3    nnet_7.3-17         withr_2.5.0        
#> [16] tidyselect_1.2.0    compiler_4.2.0      cli_3.6.1          
#> [19] rvest_1.0.2         xml2_1.3.3          sandwich_3.0-1     
#> [22] scales_1.2.0        lmtest_0.9-40       mvtnorm_1.1-3      
#> [25] digest_0.6.29       minqa_1.2.4         rmarkdown_2.14     
#> [28] pkgconfig_2.0.3     htmltools_0.5.2     lme4_1.1-29        
#> [31] dbplyr_2.1.1        fastmap_1.1.0       highr_0.9          
#> [34] rlang_1.1.1         readxl_1.4.0        rstudioapi_0.13    
#> [37] generics_0.1.2      zoo_1.8-10          jsonlite_1.8.0     
#> [40] magrittr_2.0.3      modeltools_0.2-23   Formula_1.2-4      
#> [43] Matrix_1.4-1        Rcpp_1.0.10         munsell_0.5.0      
#> [46] fansi_1.0.3         lifecycle_1.0.3     stringi_1.7.6      
#> [49] multcomp_1.4-19     yaml_2.3.5          MASS_7.3-57        
#> [52] flexmix_2.3-17      grid_4.2.0          crayon_1.5.1       
#> [55] lattice_0.20-45     haven_2.5.0         splines_4.2.0      
#> [58] hms_1.1.1           knitr_1.39          pillar_1.9.0       
#> [61] boot_1.3-28         estimability_1.4.1  codetools_0.2-18   
#> [64] stats4_4.2.0        reprex_2.0.2        glue_1.6.2         
#> [67] evaluate_0.15       mitools_2.4         modelr_0.1.8       
#> [70] vctrs_0.6.3         nloptr_2.0.1        tzdb_0.3.0         
#> [73] cellranger_1.1.0    gtable_0.3.0        assertthat_0.2.1   
#> [76] xfun_0.31           xtable_1.8-4        broom_0.8.0        
#> [79] survey_4.1-1        coda_0.19-4         survival_3.3-1     
#> [82] TH.data_1.1-1       ellipsis_0.3.2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seem to want is an (average) marginal effect. I am not an R person, so I cannot tell you what to type, but I would be very surprised (dare I say dissapointed) if there wasn't a package to do that for you.

---

**Edit**

The marginal effect is $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})\beta$. So to compute the average marginal effect, you compute the predicted proportion for each individual in your data, compute the marginal effect for each individual using the equation above, and than compute the average of these individual marginal effects.

Comment: I use emmeans to calculated such marginal effects, as detailed in the question. My issue is that I don't understand the model output well enough to perform the same calculation manually.

Comment: Does the edit answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I can now calculate the slope manually, thank you! Which resource did you check for the marginal effect formula?

Comment: I knew this one by heart